# Fixing appendix in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

In my table of contents I would like to have it say "Appendix A Regression results". However my code is giving the following output:[image]

My code is the following

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix

\section{Regression tables}
Here is the 
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I hope this helps you understanding the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please make your code compilable!

Comment: It **is** a bad idea in 99.9% of all cases to include words  in to `\thesection` etc. Please use the tocloft package and change the \cftsecnumwidth length such that the word Appendix fits into it

Comment: Will this post be improved or is it kept unclear?

Comment: Sorry @ChristianHupfer, what do you mean add words in \thesection? Like for starting a section in the text in general I do \section{Determinant Analysis}, is that bad? I tried doing what you suggested but now every word in the table contents is separated from the number. Also, maybe you could be more on how I could improve the post.

Comment: @urpi: I mean this line:  `\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}` -- it's no miracle then that the word `Appendix` does not fit into the number width part of the `ToC` -- it's filled with `\thesection`. And providing a compilable version of your post would definitely improve your post, that's been asked by CarLaTeX already

Comment: Sorry, @ChristianHupfer, I think my code now compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` will provide most of the features that are requested, rather than changing `\thesection`.

The `\Alph` - counting style of `\thesection` is the default for `article` if the `appendix` is used, `titletoc` prepends the title `Appendix A` etc. to the entry in the toc.

In order to apply the figure/table counter resetting within `section`, use `\counterwithin` from `chngcntr` package, right at the begin of `appendices`, either  manually or `\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{...}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%\appendix
\begin{appendices}
\section{Regression tables}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\end{appendices}
Here is the 
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]